# Not able to get First Name, Last Name, or Realm Id from Open Id Attributes

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

According to the [SSO documentation](https://ipp.developer.intuit.com/0010_Intuit_Partner_Platform/0025_Intuit_Anywhere/0030_Integrate_your_app/0030_Signing_Into_and_out_of_Intuit_From_Within_Your_App/Sign-in/Implement_SSO_and_OpenID_in_Your_App) for IA these attributes should be available (*I'm guessing a bit at the attributes URI*):

- First Name (http://axschema.org/namePerson/first)
- Last Name (http://axschema.org/namePerson/last)
- Realm Id (http://axschema.org/intuit/realmId)

Reviewing the query string passed during stage 3 of the open id request, here are the attributes present:

- openid.alias3.type.alias1  => http://axschema.org/namePerson
- openid.alias3.value.alias1 => Full Name
- openid.alias3.type.alias2  => http://axschema.org/contact/email
- openid.alias3.value.alias2 => email@test.com

Bug, error in the documentation, or loose nut behind the keyboard?

Comment: Hi @Michael were you able to get the firstname and lastname?

Answer (score 0):

Two problems here, the first problem is in my haste of cut and paste coding I was only requesting the full name and email. I revised the code to request first name, last name, and realm id. Now first name and last name come through fine. However, it took a big of poking around to get to the bottom of the realm id issue. First, the documentation did not give a clear answer on the attribute uri; however, I was able to find a clear answer on this thread https://idnforums.intuit.com/textthread.aspx?catid=69&threadid=16954. Paul Jackson gives a clear idea what is going on here:

1. The attribute for realm id is http://axschema.org/intuit/realmId
2. Sometimes the attribute does not come through

I put together a technique based on his suggestion in this thread. Basically, if the realm id does not come through then I'll parse it from the referring url which has it in the query string as realmId. Clearly, this is brittle but provides a "working" solution for now.

Here is a code snippet you can use during stage 3 of the handshake.

```
 _realmId = fetch.GetAttributeValue(OpenId.IntuitWellKnownRealmId);

if (_realmId == null && httpRequest.UrlReferrer != null)
{
    var url = httpRequest.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    var i = url.IndexOf('?');
    if (i != -1)
    {
        var querystring = url.Substring(i);
        _realmId = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querystring)["realmId"];
    }
}
```

I take zero credit for this solution, Paul already had it figured out. Just posting here to help anyone searching on this problem.

Comment: Can you post your code? The link is no longer valid and I am running into this same issue, thanks!